# Probability of stopping time

Tags: probability

Say I have $100,000$ different cards face down and I intend on flipping them over $1$ by $1$ and finding a specific one, how do I determine the probability of finding said card in $10$ flips? $50$?

(if you have a better title, please edit it. Don't know the best way to phrase what I'm looking for)

Comment: Hint:  it's easier to compute the probability that you don't find the card in the desired $N$ flips.

Comment: Also, you can check out the geometric distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $n$ cards total (in your example, $n=100,000$).

The probability of finding the card you want in $k$ flips is ambiguous. It could be the probability of not finding the card in $k-1$ flips, but finding it in the $k$-th flip.

That would be:

$$\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}\right)} = \dfrac{1}{n}$$

It could also mean that among the first $k$ flips, you found it, but not at exactly the $k$-th flip. This would be:

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}}{\dbinom{n}{k}} = \dfrac{k}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Probability of not finding it on the first flip is
$$\frac{99999}{100000}$$
Probability of not finding it in two flips is
$$\frac{99999}{100000} \times \frac{99998}{99999}=\frac{99998}{100000}$$
Probability of not finding it in three flips is
$$\frac{99999}{100000} \times \frac{99998}{99999} \times \frac{99997}{99998}=\frac{99997}{100000}$$
I'll let you do the generalization...